# oracle date and nls settings

Tags: oracle, nls, ora-01858

I get an ORA-01858 exception. I think it is due to NLS settings and date:

```
declare
    currentDate DATE := sysdate;
    queryString VARCHAR2(300) := '... where blablabla = :bind_timestamp ...';
    sql_cursor integer;
begin
    sql_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse(sql_cursor, queryString, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.bind_variable(sql_cursor, ':bind_timestamp', currentDate);
    rowsProcessed := dbms_sql.execute(sql_cursor);
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(sql_cursor);
end;
```

Is `dbms_sql.bind_variable(sql_cursor, ':bind_timestamp', currentDate);` NLS dependent?

I mean with some NLS settings it works normally and others it fails?

Comment: Please show us the full SQL statement. I guess the error does not stem from the usage of the `DATE` variable

Comment: Thank you, that is what I wanted to know If you make your comment an answer I will mark question as resolved.

Comment: What datatype is the column represented by `blablabla`?

Comment: Actually, all I want to know, is if this bind is nls dependent or not. Now that is resolved. I have found other issue that caused that exception. It is also related to dates (there was wrong date format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with dates, NLS settings are not relevant if you provide your own format string:

```
WHERE arrival=TO_DATE('2011-09-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

My guess is that you are relying on automatic type juggling, i.e., you are providing a string and letting Oracle cast it to date as required:

```
WHERE arrival='05/09/2011'
```

In that case, Oracle uses the default format as specified in your NLS settings.

**Update:** BTW, the [ORA-01858 code](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01858.php) means:

> a non-numeric character found where a digit was expected